# how to merge these two AndroidManifest files

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

I am currently using this AndroidManifest in my project: [Current Manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUGxA.png), however I am trying to use this other AndroidManifest from a website in order to implement an image upload service : [Manifest to add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/on3Yt.png)

I have been searching for answers but I haven't been able to merge these 2 files successfully. The Current Manifest picture of course is not the entirety of it, but I simply showed you the most important parts. Am I able to merge both packages, with both applications and activities?

**current manifest**

```
<manifest
package="org.briarproject.briar"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>

<application
    android:name="org.briarproject.briar.android.BriarApplicationImpl"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:logo="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:theme="@style/BriarTheme">

    <activity
        android:name="org.briarproject.briar.android.reporting.DevReportActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:exported="false"
```

**manifest to add**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="net.simplifiedlearning.volleymysqlexample">

<!-- the internet permission --> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: your question does not even make sense, there is nothing in the other manifest besides the read permissions that would even be useful or you dont already have in your manifest

Comment: so you're saying all other attributes are useless to have? what about the package?

Comment: the package has nothing to do with your app or taking a picture

Comment: Have you read [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)?

In order to upload an image, you need to add a permission. You should not "merge" the manifests.

Comment: so basically I shouldn't do anything?

Comment: Even after solving the issue, you should read the documentation that @MargaritaLitkevych linked so that you understand what each element in the XML is for and why you need some pieces and not others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you *still* want to *merge* them (or still are wondering how to do it, *after* reading other peoples comments) ?.

*If so* (you could have used a separate module or make a library), *one way is* like this:

- I kept your old `package name` as the external `main` one
- I made sure I had **all** permissions of **both** `manifest's`
- I kept the new Activity's `intent-filter` (so it's the first Activity on launch)
- You need to physically copy the new source code (directory/s) into your current source code
  `("net.simplifiedlearning.volleymysqlexample.MainActivity"` meaning physically `"...\net\simplifiedlearning\volleymysqlexample\MainActivity"` {*windows path convention*})

Merging `manifest's` is quite a *simple* operation, merging `resources` can be a *lot of work*. Questions you have to ask yourself:

- Do I need `resources` from the new project and *copy/merge* them into the current ?
  (They *may* be *many* and *incompatible*, `strings`,`layouts`, `styles` and `themes` in particular but *many* more ...).
- Is the build system of the new project merged into your project ?

Example resource directories (*not* to mention *all* the files):

```
res +
    +---drawable-hdpi
    +---drawable-land-hdpi
    +---drawable-land-ldpi
    +---drawable-land-mdpi
    +---drawable-land-xhdpi
    +---drawable-land-xxhdpi
    +---drawable-land-xxxhdpi
    +---drawable-mdpi
    +---drawable-port-hdpi
    +---drawable-port-ldpi
    +---drawable-port-mdpi
    +---drawable-port-xhdpi
    +---drawable-port-xxhdpi
    +---drawable-port-xxxhdpi
    +---drawable-xhdpi
    +---drawable-xxhdpi
    +---layout
    +---menu
    +---mipmap-hdpi
    +---mipmap-ldpi
    +---mipmap-mdpi
    +---mipmap-xhdpi
    +---mipmap-xxhdpi
    +---mipmap-xxxhdpi
    +---values
    +---xml
```

The merged `manifest`:

```
    <manifest
    package="org.briarproject.briar"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>

    <application
        android:name="org.briarproject.briar.android.BriarApplicationImpl"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:theme="@style/BriarTheme">

    <activity android:name="org.briarproject.briar.android.reporting.DevReportActivity">
        android:label="@string/crash_report_title"
    </activity>

        <activity android:name="net.simplifiedlearning.volleymysqlexample.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I understood my problem, and that basically everything was uselesss except the code permissions, thank you for your help I

Comment: No problem @david benalal ;O)

Answer (score 0):

your code shows two differentes packages, anyway, merge several manifest is a gradle or IDE task:

"Your APK file can contain just one AndroidManifest.xml file, but your Android Studio project may contain several—provided by the main source set, build variants, and imported libraries. So when building your app, the Gradle build merges all manifest files into a single manifest file that's packaged into your APK."

source: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html

Comment: So I could create another androidmanifest file in the same folder?